# Принять Json в c# через System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json

Нужно распарсить Json ответ, как это сделать правильно?

Принимаем это.
JSON:

```
{
"info1": 0,     
"info2": "OK",                
"info3": "",                                             
"info4": [
    {
        "a": "11a",                
        "b": "12b",                  
        "c": 33,                    
        "d": "13ac"                       
    },
    {
        "a": "1a",                 
        "b": "2b",                  
        "c": 52,                     
        "d": "3c"                      
    }
],
"f": "13"
}
```

Я использую `using System.Text.Json`

Принимаю ответ от сервера в строку и пытаюсь забрать значения в класс

```
string result = stream.ReadToEnd();
ResultDone res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OrderBookDone>(result);
```

Сам класс

```
 class ResultDone
    {
        public int info1 { get; set; }
        public string info2 { get; set; }
        public string info3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Тут код работает нормально, всё собирается.
Но как мне собрать данные из `info4`?

Comment: Скопируйте ваш json в буфер, зайдите на сайт http://json2csharp.com/ вставьте и сгенерируйте нужные классы.

Comment: Так просто? Спасибо!

Comment: Можно еще проще. Скопировать в буфер, и в студии есть Paste Special опция, чтобы студия создала классы.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, за годное замечание.